# Change column based on other two columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 5, ncol = 1))
colnames(df) <- "father"
df$father <- c("A", "B", "B","C","D")
df$id <- c("C", "E","F","G","H")
df$pop <- c("ref","ref","ref","val","val")
```

Which gives:

```
  father id pop
1      A  C ref
2      B  E ref
3      B  F ref
4      C  G val
5      D  H val
```

Then if "id" appears in "father", the value of the pop should be the one that appears in the row of the father.
For example in this example "C" appears both in "father" and in "id", in father C the pop is val, then, I want the pop of C as id to be val as follows:

```
  father id pop
1      A  C val 
2      B  E ref
3      B  F ref
4      C  G val
5      D  H val
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following

```r
require(dplyr)
require(magrittr)

merge(x = df,
      y = df,
      by.x = 'id',
      by.y = 'father',
      all.x = T) %>% 
  mutate(., pop = ifelse(is.na(pop.y), pop.x, pop.y)) %>%
  subset(., select = c('father', 'id', 'pop'))
```

The idea is to perform a left join onto itself by `merge` (since `all.x=T`), and select the wanted value by `mutate`.

Comment: Thanks! It works! In addition, if there are repeated id we should add a line to remove the duplicates :) For example, if the new dataframe is called "populations" we should apply:  populations = populations[!duplicated(populations$id),]

Comment: @ana_gg what if in your example, the ``id`` is ``B``? E.g., ``df$id <- c("B", "E","F","G","H")``? Which ``pop`` value would you assign? Unless they will always be the same, then yes, duplicate entries will be present, as you say!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have adjusted the example, it never happens. All the "id" from a father are assigned to the same populations always :)

Comment: @runr code golf : you don't have to attach `magrittr` if you don't need any other operator from `magrittr` such as `%<>%`. attaching `dplyr` brings `%>%` at the same time and `left_join` from `dplyr` can be used instead of `merge` for a bit more human readability.